# Splitting XAML Empty-Element Tags in Visual Studio

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2010

Quick question, and I hope I'm using the right terminology :)

I'm using Visual Studio 10. Is there a keyboard shorcut for splitting an empty element tag?

For example, I want to turn:

```
<element />
```

into:

```
<element></element>
```

quickly. This is just a minor nuisance, but editing XAML, for a beginner like me, is very time consuming. I spend a lot of time just splitting up tags to add attributes. I was just hoping there was some sort of shortcut in VS for this.

Thanks!
Jerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resharper does it, but I don't think VS can do it out of the box...

Anyway, there's a quick way to split a tag: delete the closing sequence ("/>"), and just add an closing angled bracket (">"): VS will automatically create the closing tag

Comment: Ha, I just figured that out and was coming back here to answer my own question. I dont know how I havent figured that already, but whatever. Thanks for the answer!